# How to Merge Sales and Purchage Query in One Query?

Tags: mysql, laravel-9

This is my code. I fetch the data from same table for sales, and purchase. But the problem is, I cannot merge the two queries into one.

I want to make report date wise for both. First check the date for purchase and sales. If purchase  has made then sale should subtract from purchase on same date.

Here is my code live link: https://mmimonir.xyz/vat_purchage_homepage

How i achieve this?

```
$purchage_data = Core::rightJoin('vehicles', 'vehicles.model_code', '=', 'cores.model_code')
            ->select(
                'cores.id',                
                'cores.model_code',                
                'cores.vat_code',                
                'vehicles.model',
                'cores.uml_mushak_no',
                'cores.mushak_date',
                'cores.vat_rebate',
                DB::raw('MONTH(cores.mushak_date) as month'),
                DB::raw('1 as quantity')
            )
            ->where('cores.vat_code', "=", $vat_code)
            ->whereBetween('cores.mushak_date', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->orderBy('cores.mushak_date', 'asc')            
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(['model', 'month', 'uml_mushak_no']);

$sale_data = Core::rightJoin('vehicles', 'vehicles.model_code', '=', 'cores.model_code')
            ->select(
                'cores.id',
                'cores.customer_name',
                'cores.nid_no',
                'cores.model_code',
                'cores.full_address',
                'cores.vat_code',
                'cores.five_chassis',
                'cores.five_engine',
                'cores.vat_sale_date',
                'cores.sale_mushak_no',
                'cores.basic_price_vat',
                'cores.sale_vat',
                'cores.unit_price_vat',
                'vehicles.model',
                'cores.uml_mushak_no',
                'cores.mushak_date',
                DB::raw('MONTH(cores.vat_sale_date) as month'),
                DB::raw('1 as quantity')
            )
            ->where('cores.vat_code', "=", $vat_code)
            ->whereBetween('cores.vat_sale_date', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->orderBy('cores.sale_mushak_no', 'asc')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(['model', 'month', 'vat_sale_date']);
```

Comment: Your queries have different grouping expressions and different amount of output columns.

Comment: You can join the same table with itself.  However, it will not work if you want different columns for each portion and/or different grouping.  If you can specify a merged list of columns, then it can be achieved.    Please use a dbfiddle to load the schema, your query and some sample data.

Comment: Are you wanting multiple rows, like a report ?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by joining the two tables together with `SQL Join`.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales
INNER JOIN Purchases ON Sales.SaleID=Purchase.PurchaseID;
```

[Check out W3Schools for a more in-depth explanation.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: But sale and purchase data are in same table. It's a motorcycle database. One row for one motorcycle.